# Link error when trying to test a cpp11 function

Tags: c++11, cmake, googletest

So I have a very simple class that contains two function and a member, this is from header file:

```
public:
    void addMethod(std::string methodName);
    std::vector<std::string> getResponse();
    std::vector<std::string> methodList;
```

and this is definitions from source file:

```
std::vector<std::string> MethodsList::getResponse() {
    return methodList;
}

void MethodsList::addMethod(std::string methodName)
{
    methodList.push_back(methodName);
}
```

And i have a very basic test file just to test this :

```
TEST (MyTestSuit, addMethod) {
    MethodsList ListOfMethods;
    std::string methodName = "GetMethods";
    ListOfMethods.addMethod(methodName);
    ASSERT_EQ(rpcMethods.getResponse()[0], methodName);
}
```

But when i try to compile this i get link error as :

```
methods_test.cpp:(.text+0x86): undefined reference to
`MethodsList::addMethod(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
 std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So at first sight it looks like the library i am using (googletest) is not compiled with c++11 support but actually i am not using precompiled library, thus i don't think it is the issue.

Here you can check some part of my CMakeList :

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

include_directories(src include)
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES      "src/*.cpp" "src/*.h")
file(GLOB PUBLIC_HEADERS    "include/*.h")

add_library(${TARGET} SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES} ${PUBLIC_HEADERS})
set(TEST_FILES "${SOURCE_FILES}" "${PUBLIC_HEADERS}")
include(AddGMock)
include(AddGTestTest)
add_gmock()
add_gtest_test(API_tests ${TEST_FILES} ${TARGET})

configure_file(template-library.pc.in template-library.pc @ONLY)
...some install commands...
```

So how can i solve this error ? Any idea ?

Comment: Hmm. as I understand the error, linker misses **definition** of `MethodsList::addMethod`. Where is this method defined? [Class definition contains only *declaration* of the method.]

Comment: The method is defined in class header. i have copied couple of lines from the class header up there (the first snippet)

Comment: Class header only **declares** the method - it only specifies its *signature*. For using method, it should have **definition** somewhere: `void MethodsList::addMethod(std::string methodName) { /*code*/ }`.

Comment: I have definition in cpp file, for preventing misunderstanding i have added functions definitions as well.

Comment: Module `AddGTestTest` - where did you get it? And what its `add_gtest_test` function does? If module is same as [this one](https://github.com/Pelagicore/softwarecontainer/blob/master/cmake_modules/AddGTestTest.cmake), then its `add_gtest_test` function accepts **libraries** as its 3d argument, but you passes `"${PUBLIC_HEADERS}"` instead (your *TEST_FILES* is actually a list of two values: one value contains source files, and the second - header files).